# Conditions for development of sonus medius

Tags: etymology, phonology

### Background

It is fairly generally accepted that all Proto-Italic short vowels in medial (= unstressed, but non-final) syllables largely merged on the way to Classical Latin as **e* (further developing to *i* except before *r* or consonant clusters), with some conditioning factors, such as the outcome being *o* > *u* before *L pinguis*, rather than **e* or *i*.

It’s also well-known that before a (single) labial consonant, there was some vacillation between ⟨i⟩ and ⟨u⟩ in writing (e.g., *optimus ~ optumus*, *documentum ~ docimentum*), especially in older Latin. We have evidence from contemporary writers that these words were pronounced with a vowel intermediate between /i/ and /u/, know as **sonus medius** and probably pronounced something like [ɨ ~ ʉ ~ ʏ] or perhaps just a simple schwa [ə].

###### Distribution of *sonus medius*

Many of the words that exhibit *sonus medius* are fairly opaque; it’s particularly frequent in the superlative suffix *-i/umus*, the dat./abl.pl. suffix *-bus* and before derivative suffixes in *-ment-* and *-fex*, for instance, where the actual vowel quality doesn’t relate to any root. But there are also cases where it appears in quite transparent compounds, even parallel cases where different spellings become standard (e.g., [*auceps*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/auceps) ‘bird catcher’ has gen. *auc**u**pis*, but [*princeps*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/princeps#Latin) lit. ‘first-catcher’ has gen. *princ**i**pis*).

In these cases, the presence of rounded and/or front vowels in adjacent syllables seems to play *some* part, but it’s hard to say to what extent. For instance, **ob-cap-ō* becomes *occ**u**pō* (according to De Vaan derived from an unattested intermediate noun **ob-caps* > **occeps*, gen. **occupis*), but **ob-capiō* becomes *occ**i**piō*, possibly due to the /j/ in the following syllable. Analogy can also frequently sway the result one way or the other; e.g., *surruptus* instead of *surreptus* (from **sub-rapiō*) could be due to analogy with *ruptus* (from *rumpō*).

### Missing *sonus medius*

All this is quite well-documented and fairly understandable from a phonological point of view. What I can’t really find any mention of is the many places where we would **expect** to find *sonus medius*, but in actual fact do not, ever.

The primary category here is verbs with preverbs attached. We do find some verbs that vacillate between ⟨i⟩ and ⟨u⟩, particularly in forms that have adjacent rounded vowels (e.g., perfect *surrupuit* and *surripuit* or derived verbs like *occupō* mentioned above), but they seem to be few and far between. In most cases, we don’t seem to find any indication of ⟨u⟩ at all, even in forms that provide ample environment for it. For example, I have been unable to find a single instance of *any* compound verb containing *premō* ‘press’ or *emō* ‘buy/get’ that has ⟨u⟩ – no *†opprumunt* or *†perumunt* or anything like that.

Analogy is one possible reason for this, but it seems rather a weak analogy, all things considered: it wouldn’t be restoring the root’s vowel (it’s not *†oppremō* or *†peremō*), but only undoing what was presumably a more or less automatic and subphonemic change in unstressed, reduced vowels before labials.

The trouble is that I can’t find much discussion on *sonus medius* that gives more than a handful of cherry-picked examples of it. Nothing I’ve been able to locate provides a decent dataset, both of forms where we *do* see *sonus medius* and forms where we *don’t*.

##### Have the precise conditions determining whether a reduced vowel surfaces as *sonus medius* been mapped out anywhere?